# jQuery mobile input field error stylings

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile for a few form pages on an HTML5-based mobile site I'm working on. jQuery mobile has some good form stylings out of the box but I can't see much for highlighting when a field contains an error.

I'd expect you could highlight an erroneous input field with a red background colour and have a tooltip popup above the field explaining what's wrong to the user with some extra classes and input field properties.

Short of implementing all this myself, jQuery mobile doesn't have anything like that out of the box. Can anyone point me in the direction of some decent styling libraries for showing errors in jQuery mobile forms?

Comment: Did you resolve your situation? If so, how? You could push in your own answer. The only one that is here is more of a workaround/fallback.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) has some really attractive styling for things of this nature. It has form some form specific classes, tooltips, as well as alert functionality built in. I would suggest though that you use the [customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) feature to only use the parts of the framework that you need.

I also stumbled across [Formee](http://www.formee.org/) but I still prefer bootstrap.

Comment: The only thing about bootstrap is that it doesn't seem to be as well optimised for touch as jQuery mobile. I've got a lot of templates already integrated into my app which use JM.

Answer (score 0):

By default if you have in your model
      validates_presence_of :name

In case of error you get this html in your JQM. The problem is that label and input get wrapped by divs with class field_with_errors. This breaks layout of JQM

```
<fieldset data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <label for="case_name" class="ui-input-text">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field_with_errors">
    <input type="text" value="" size="30" name="case[name]" id="case_name" class="ui-input-text ui-body-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

There are several options to fix this, [Rails 3: "field-with-errors" wrapper changes the page appearance. How to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5267998/1416023)

I used this answer to rewrite default wrapping of the label and input of the invalid field in unobtrusive way for JQM, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380400/1416023

Created file error_output.rb in config/initializers with the following content

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  class_attr_index = html_tag.index 'class="'
  if class_attr_index
    html_tag.insert class_attr_index+7, 'field_with_errors '
  else
    html_tag.insert html_tag.index('>'), ' class="field_with_errors"'
  end
end
```

Added the following css to my application.css in app/assets

```
label.field_with_errors{
 color:#C45457;
}
```

Now the label of the invalid field is in red color.

Extra:
I output validation errors in JQM collapsible with partial layouts/error_messages.html.haml

Put this into your form file.

```
=render "layouts/error_messages", entity: @case
```

The layouts/error_messages.html.haml

```
- if entity.errors.any?
  %div{:data => {:role=>"collapsible", :collapsed=>"false", :theme=>"e", :'content-theme'=>"b"}}
    %h4
      = pluralize(entity.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited saving:
    - entity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %p= msg
```

Hope this helps you to implement error reporting in JQM

Answer (score 0):

You could change the data-theme classes. Use jQuery Mobile Themeroller (http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php) to create a theme that marks an input as erroneous. 
Then look here: [Jquery mobile: Change theme on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972140/jquery-mobile-change-theme-on-click)
This Combination helped me to realise that.