# jQuery append to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

What I want to do is, to create a button and this button is pressed, it will change the theme color on my jQuery mobile test site.

So say that my html parent div looks like this

```
<div id="firstPage" data-role="page">
```

I want it so that on click, that it appends `data-theme="theme letter here"`
to the div so that it ends up like this `<div id="firstPage" data-role="page" data-theme="theme letter here">`

OR

If I start the div like this `<div id="firstPage" data-role="page" data-theme="theme letter here">` That on the buttons click, that it changes that data-theme attribute to another letter

so something for example, like this

```
$('#themeBtn').click(function(){
        $('#firstPage').setAttribute("data-role","ANOTHER theme letter");   
    });
```

or

```
$('#themeBtn').click(function(){
        $('#firstPage').append("data-role","a");    
    });
```

or something like this. How can I properly go about this?

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT*** based on the responses, ive tried**

```
/////////////TESTING THEME BUTTON (check STACK OVERFLOW for answer)
$('#themeBtn').click(function(){
    //$('#firstPage').jqmData("role","a");
    //$('#firstPage').attr("data-theme","a");
    //$('#firstPage').jqmData("theme","a");
    $('#firstPage').data('theme','a');
});
```

To make sure that the button is firing off, i commented all those lines out and did a simple

```
$('#themeBtn').click(function(){
    alert("foo");
    });
```

and sure enough it fired the alert on button click so im positive its working.(the button i mean).

**I added a jsFiddle** so you can see it in action(of not working lol)
http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/yRmKd/1/
if you un-comment the alert, itll fire off, when you uncomment the other lines(based on responses) it doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jqmData` method:

```
$('#firstPage').jqmData('role', 'a');
```

[docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

> When working with jQuery Mobile, jqmData and jqmRemoveData should be
>   used in place of jQuery core's data and removeData methods (note that
>   this includes $.fn.data, $.fn.removeData, and the $.data,
>   $.removeData, and $.hasData utilities), as they automatically
>   incorporate getting and setting of namespaced data attributes (even if
>   no namespace is currently in use).

Comment: doesn't jQuery Mobile use jqmData() instead? docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, ive edited my post to show what ive tried based on the reply, and its not working.

Comment: @somdow: You had some unclosed quotes in your HTML. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/yRmKd/1/.

Comment: @somdow If you are looking to change the entire theme, there'll be more stuff involved instead of just changing the attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972140/jquery-mobile-change-theme-on-click

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `$('#firstPage').data('theme', 'ANOTHER theme letter');`

Comment: doesn't jQuery Mobile use jqmData() instead? docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, ive edited my post to show what ive tried based on the reply, and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to set the attribute:

```
   $('#themeBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#firstPage').attr("data-theme", "new Theme");   
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, ive edited my post to show what ive tried based on the reply, and its not working

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
$('#themeBtn').click(function(){
    $('#firstPage').attr("data-role","ANOTHER theme letter");   
});
```

This should update the data-role

Comment: Hello Daniel, Yep i tried that at first and it didnt update. i then tried .removeAttr and it didnt remove it. to MAKE SURE that the button was targeted and firing off, i commented them all out and added a alert('foo'); and sure enough on click it alerted so the button is working. Just cant seem to fire off the theme change on click